# WPF DataTemplate displays ToString

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm working on a small little program and trying to follow MVVM approach using DataTemplate to create view for my VMs.  Problem I'm running into is that instead of creating an instance of the view it appears to be showing the ToString() result of the VM instead.  If I put a breakpoint on constructor for the View class (MainNavigation.xaml) it is never reached.

Code below, help appreciated.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Tester.Wpf.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tester.Wpf"
    xmlns:scr="clr-namespace:Tester.Wpf.Screens"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="x:Type scr:MainNavigationViewModel">
        <scr:MainNavigation />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ContentControl Name="MainNav" Content="{Binding MainNavigationViewModel2}" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using Tester.Wpf.Screens;

namespace Tester.Wpf
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private MainNavigationViewModel _mainNavigationViewModel;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.DataContext = this;
            this.MainNavigationViewModel2 = new MainNavigationViewModel();

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public MainNavigationViewModel MainNavigationViewModel2
        {
            get { return _mainNavigationViewModel; }
            set { _mainNavigationViewModel = value;
                RaisePropertyChangedEvent("MainNavigationViewModel2");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

MainNavigation.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Tester.Wpf.Screens
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainNavigation.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainNavigation : UserControl
    {
        public MainNavigation()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

MainNavigationViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Tester.Wpf.Helpers;

namespace Tester.Wpf.Screens
{
    public class MainNavigationViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public int Test = 10;
    }
}
```

MainNavigation.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Tester.Wpf.Screens.MainNavigation"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tester.Wpf.Screens"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <Grid Background="Blue">
         <TextBlock>YOU"VE MADE IT!</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: What is `MainNavigationViewModel2`? There is no such property and you aren't setting `DataContext` anywhere. Check for binding errors in Output window, they should be pretty self-explainable. I suggest you to find MVVM tutorial and follow it (e.g. [this one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/index.htm)).

Comment: Sorry added the code there now.  Will check out the tutorial, thanks.  Have checked many (seems to be tons) but for some reason can't get this working and probably something stupid and small.

Comment: You don't need to rise notification if you first set the property and then set DataContext. One thing which bugs me is what you doing it before `InitializeComponents`.

Comment: Thanks for tip.  Doesn't fix the main problem but reduces code some.

Comment: Hard to spot, but you misuse [`x:Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/x-type-markup-extension) xaml extension. Put it inside `{ }`.

Comment: That was it!  Knew it'd be stupid and yeah difficult to spot it seems, no complaints from anything.  Thanks a ton.

Comment: Hah, I spotted it in the first five seconds, but that's just me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In MainWindow.xaml file changed the following line based on Sinatr's comment:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="x:Type scr:MainNavigationViewModel">
```

to

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type scr:MainNavigationViewModel}">
```